# ASP.net core 3.1 List is populated in the onGet but not in OnPost. What is the correct way to bind it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

The `PostsList` is getting populated correctly in the `OnGet` method and is correctly populating a loop in HTML. In the `OnPostDeletePost` method its null. How can i bind a list correctly so that its populated in the entire model ??

Model:

```
public List<Post> PostsList { get; set; }

public async Task OnGet(string userId){

    PostsList = await _db.Posts.Include(p => p.ApplicationUser).Where(p => p.ApplicationUserId == userId).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).ToListAsync();

}


public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeletePost(int? postId)
{
    if(postId == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var postToDelete = PostsList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == postId);
    if(postToDelete == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    _db.Posts.Remove(postToDelete);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToPage("Profile", new { userId = ApplicationUser.Id });
}
```

Comment: Everytime there is a request a new instance is created so you would have to call your _db again.....

Answer (score 0):

Every request is a new instance of the page model.
You can tell MVC to bind the list from form values;

```cs
[BindProperty]
public List<Post> PostsList { get; set; }
```

But I assume you mean to reload from the database? Note that you can load just the record you want to delete;

```cs
var post = await _db.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == postId).SingleOrDefaultAsync()
...
_db.Posts.Remove(post);
```

Comment: Hello Jeremy, yes i already loaded the record in the way you suggested before posting the question. My issue is that it doesnt seem efficient to load and parse the entire Posts table every time a user wants to delete a post. I want to load it once when in the OnGet method, populate the public List<Post> PostsList { get; set; }
 and then use it in the OnPost method.

Comment: You don't need to load a record from the database in order to delete it. So long as you populate the key and concurrency fields, the correct sql will be generated. eg `_db.Posts.Remove(new Post{Id = postId});`.

Comment: The key point here is that you can't trivially share any state between `OnGet` and `OnPost` as they are separate requests.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your response. Would you be able to provide some help about using signalR for chatting with a specific user by any chance. Thank you again.